# Know if a UINotification has gone off when applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

I want to know when a UINotification has gone off when the user doesn't launch the app via touching on the notification itself but by fast app switching or homescreen icon.

I've checked `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]` but after the notifications have fired this array is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once localnotification is fire that will show in notification center ,it will not show it in `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]`.

if your app is in active state that will call `didreceivelocalnotification` but when your app is not in active state it will show in notification center.

So it will remain in notification center untill you clear it.

if You want to get you can check it in appdelegate method with `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method.

```
 UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif)
    {
        NSLog(@"lcoal:%@",[localNotif userInfo]);
        UIAlertView *al=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Challenge gehaald!" message:@"Gefeliciteerd, je hebt deze bonus challenge succesvol afgerond." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [al show];
    }
```